# Making it so users that do not have macros enabled cannot see other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am working on a project that wants all users to have macros enabled. It is a shared sheet so I cannot simply hide everything as a baseline and unhide the sheets when Open_Workbook is ran. My goal is to make it so only my designated "BLANK" sheet is shown when macros are disabled.

Using the 'Browser View' feature of the workbook, I've been able to make it only open to the "BLANK" sheet if on browser or teams, I want to do that here but with a check for enabled macros, or a default state that can be switched on with the enabling of macros.

A means of stopping someone from using the sheet entirely if they do not have macros enabled would also work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this trick by setting the other sheets than "BLANK" to be
"very hidden".

There are three "Visible" properties for a sheet :

- xlSheetVisible (or TRUE) - the sheet is visible
- xlSheetHidden (or FALSE) - the sheet is hidden
- xlSheetVeryHidden - the sheet is very hidden

One can toggle using the Excel visual interface between the states
of Visible and Hidden by using the Unhide or Hide commands.
However, only a Visual Basic macro can set or unset the
`xlVeryHidden` value, or it can also be manually done from the
VBA Editor.

**How to make a worksheet very hidden**

The workbook must be stored in `.xlsm` format, and then do the following:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
  or click in the the Developer tab the Visual Basic button to open
  the Visual Basic Editor.
  You will see the Project Explorer window in the top-left panel.
- Press <kbd>F4</kbd> or click *View > Properties* to open the
  Properties window just below (if not already there)
- In the Project Explorer window, click to select the worksheet
  to make very hidden
- In the Properties window, set the Visible property to
  "2 - xlSheetVeryHidden".

That's it : save and close the workbook.
The hidden worksheets will now be totally and very hidden.

**Showing very hidden worksheets**

To unhide the very hidden worksheets will require a VBA macro,
so that when macros are disabled they will stay hidden.

This macro will unhide all worksheets :

```
Sub UnhideVeryHiddenSheets()
Dim wks As Worksheet
For Each wks In Worksheets
  If wks.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
    wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next
End Sub
```

The macro can also set the BLANK worksheet to hidden with
a code-line like this:

```
Sheets("BLANK").Visible = False
```

To create a macro that will do that automatically when the
workbook is opened, see the Microsoft article
[Automatically run a macro when opening a workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44).

References :

- [Hide sheets and use the xlVeryHidden constant in a macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/hide-sheet-and-use-xlveryhidden)
- [Very hidden sheets in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/very-hidden-sheets-excel/)

Comment: You will need a on_close macro to re-hide the sheets when closing the workbook otherwise if the workbook was saved previously the sheets would be visible if opened again

Comment: With this project there will be many people on the workbook at the same time as it is a shared workbook. This means that Hidden states are off the table unless there is a way to hide / unhide locally rather than globally. If there is, please let me know!

Comment: @ThomasWohllaib: I have no experience in such an environment. Does the macro execute locally on the document or for everybody?

Comment: @harrymc Hiding sheets is a global operation so every time a new user were to open the workbook it would hide/unhide the sheets for all users based on who had just opened the sheet.

Comment: It seems to me that your approach is overly complicated. A simpler approach might be to put BLANK in a separate workbook, containing a VBA macro to open the real document with a secret password. The macro will need to be well hidden, but will be the only way to access without knowing the password.